# how to create maven project with gwt 2.4.0

Tags: gwt, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am using Eclipse(indigo) and installed maven plugins from 
   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/release

I don't understand which catalog and also archetype used from list.
what is Group-Id and Artifact-Id ? what is the use of these ids in project?

Comment: WHy do you want to use Maven if you don't know Maven? Maybe start by reading about it? ⇒ http://maven.apache.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is step by step procedure to create a GWT maven project in eclipse

http://uptick.com.au/content/getting-started-gwt-maven-and-eclipse

Here is video link : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea1vSx8aDXk

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

**groupId** `will identify your project uniquely across all projects`

**artifactId** `is the name of the jar without version.`

Please refer [maven Naming Conventions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)

**UPDATE:**

Forgot to mention about catalog .There are already `standard catalog files`. Use them.

These are standard [catalog](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/archetype-catalog.html) files which contain information about `Archetypes` so that users can be presented with a list of `archetypes` from any number of `catalogs` to generate new `projects`.

Comment: ok and when we create project which catalog select and also which archetype use?

Comment: You have to create a local archtype catalog ..let me give a link http://code.google.com/p/maven-gwt-archetypes/wiki/usage .Hope that helps and push you further .Good luck .